# restore docker images from backup

Tags: docker

Trying to load docker images from a backup drive which is mounted on `/mnt`. This is a new Ubuntu install and in `/var/lib/docker` there are no images but they are there in `/mnt/var/lib/docker`.

I thought about `rsync /mnt/var/lib/docker/ /var/lib/docker/`. There is currently nothing in `/var/lib/docker` I need to save. But hesitating, since if it doesn't work, docker would break.

There is also the `import` command in the docs

`$ sudo tar -c . | docker import - exampleimagedir`

but not sure if this means I should cd into `/mnt/var/lib/docker` and run `sudo tar -c .` from there?

Any suggestions appreciated. Just want to restore the docker images and containers in the `/mnt/var/lib/docker` directory into the current running docker on the same host.
I do not want to move `/var/lib/docker` to another location.

Comment: Seems like you might as well just try your `rsync` idea first. If docker breaks, just `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*` and try something else.

Comment: I'd delete all of `/var/lib/docker`, [restore named volumes from backup](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#restore-container-from-backup), and either `docker build` or `docker pull` the images as appropriate.  Aside from the named volume content there "shouldn't" be anything there that can't be recreated.

Comment: @DavidMaze Just curious, how come I always see ya give your answers in a comment rather than an actual answer? Is it for a badge or something? I see others do this sometimes as well, lol.

Comment: If I'm suggesting a different starting point from the question ("ignore the backup of `/var/lib/docker`"), it doesn't necessarily resolve things for the asker ("but this backup is all I have"; "but there actually is data only in the container filesystem").  On other questions I've definitely gotten a mix of responses to suggesting a fundamentally different approach, and unless I can answer the question with technical facts, I'll usually put it as a comment.

Comment: `rsync` didn't work, but I these steps allowed me to do what I needed:  
1. change the docker dir to `/mnt/var/lib/docker`
2. export the desired images to tar files
3. change the docker dir back to `/var/lib/docker`
4. import the tarred images  
thanks for the helpful comments.